# Why I get this error when I try to open my Xamarin.Mac project "MonoDevelop.MonoMac.XamMac2ProjectFlavor"?

Tags: xamarin.forms, monodevelop, xamarin.mac

When I try to open my Xamarin.Mac project I receive this error, any ideas?

> Error while trying to load the project
>   '/Users/eduardo/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject.MacOs/MyProject.MacOs.csproj':
>   The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.MonoMac.XamMac2ProjectFlavor'
>   threw an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just released that I need to have installed Xamarin.Mac with Visual Studio
[image]

- Open your Visual Studio for Mac Installer
- Make sure that the macOs (Cocoa) option is checked